# Export every line (excpet last line ) of a file to create a new file for each line using AWK

Tags: linux, unix, awk, scripting, gnu

For example if there are n no of lines, then n-1 no of files should be created.
Here is what i have achieved so far. I am manually inserting 8 (i.e. total no of lines). I dont know how to get total no of lines in a variable and then use it.

```
awk '{if (NR<8) F=NR".ndjson"; print >> F; close (F)}' export.ndjson
```

Comment: Without awk, I would use `split -l 1 file.txt`, and then remove the last file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to print every line to its own file, except the last line.

```
$ awk 'p{close(f); f="object"(NR-1)".ndjson"; print p > f} {p=$0}' file
```

note also that empty lines won't create empty files.

The logic is simply to delay printing by one record.

Comment: this is exactly what i needed. But if i want to save files like object1.ndjson, object 2.ndjson...and so on. How to achieve that?

Comment: That will fail when a line in the input file evaluates numerically to zero. You should be testing `NR>1` instead of `p` for robustness and clarity but of course then your answer is identical to mine.

Answer (score 1):

One of the way IMHO could be take total number of lines by `wc` command then store it to a variable. Fair warning since  OP has now shown samples so couldn't test it and edited/tweaked OP's attempt here.

```
awk -v lines="$(wc -l < "export.ndjson")" '{if (NR<lines) F=NR".ndjson"; print >> F; close (F)}' export.ndjson
```

***NOTE:*** Another way could be read your Input_file `export.ndjson` 2 times where take its number of total lines in 1st time(only number of lines) and 2nd time its execution we could use that count to be used in condition.

---

---

***2nd solution:*** If my assumption is correct and you want to leave last line only then you could try `tac` + `awk` combination where first line could be left.

```
tac export.ndjson | awk 'FNR>1{F=NR".ndjson"; print >> F; close (F)}'
```

Comment: in 2nd suggestion, you may need to correct the order of lines(if you bother about it), since `tac` will reverse the line order.

Comment: In both of your solution, i was able to fetch n-2 lines only. What i needed was n-1. But thanks for your suggestions.I found @karakfa answer more close to what i needed.

Answer (score 1):

If you want your output file numbers to start at 2:

```
awk 'NR>1{out=NR".json"; print prev > out; close(out)} {prev=$0}' export.ndjson
```

or at 1:

```
awk 'NR>1{out=(NR-1)".json"; print prev > out; close(out)} {prev=$0}' export.ndjson
```

or:

```
awk 'NR>1{print prev > out; close(out)} {prev=$0; out=NR".json"}' export.ndjson
```